# Putting a bitmap drawable into an array

Tags: java, android

So I have this image adapter class and a nav class. In the nav class I listen to the onclick of a button and then put the image into a URi. After that I convert it to a bitmap drawable. So my question is how can I put this drawable into my array in the imageadapter ?

Please note: I am passing the bitmap drawable from the nav.class to the image adapter.class.

> nav class:

```
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK){
        imageuri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageuri);
            d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            returndrawble();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

> image adapter class:

```
public Drawable returndrawble(){
    return d;
}

}

 private Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.test, R.drawable.test2, R.drawable.test3, R.drawable.test4, R.drawable.test5, R.drawable.test6, R.drawable.test7, R.drawable.test8,
    };

    public imageadapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        //nav nav = new nav();
        //image = nav.d;
    }
```

> whole nav class:

```
public class nav extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    public static String email;
    public static final int IMAGE_PICK= 100;
    static Uri imageuri;
    public static Drawable d;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

         */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);
        // get Value passed with Intent
        try {
            email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar == null)
            System.err.println("error");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() == null)
            System.err.println("error");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle(email);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hamburger));
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_message:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                toolbar2.setTitle("messages");
            break;

            case R.id.nav_image:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ImageFragment()).commit();
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                toolbar.setTitle("images");
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notes:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new NotesFragment()).commit();
                Toolbar toolbar1 = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                toolbar1.setTitle("notes");
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen((GravityCompat.START))){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // check which nav item
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.addimage:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                openGallery();
                break;
            case R.id.loggout:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(nav.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void openGallery(){
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE_PICK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK){
                imageuri = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageuri);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                    returndrawble();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    }
    public Drawable returndrawble(){
        return d;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You want to know how you can add a drawable variable to an array at runtime?

Comment: correct that is what I am trzing to figure out

Comment: Into which array? The array you posted is an integer array. You cannot put drawables in it as a drawable is no integer.

Comment: I have an approach that would help you solve this problem.. but first, I need to know.. Are you inflating the adapter in your Nav class?

Comment: I edited it above thanks for helping Taslim Oseni